# How long do enchanted item defensive effects last?

Tags: dresden-files

The rules on crafting seem to cover a lot of things, but one thing that seems to be missing is duration.

If I craft a ring that gives me a +5 defensive block, does that last for one exchange?  Until the start of my next round?  What about armor -- looking at the books, it seems like the duster *must* provide a lasting benefit, but the duster description doesn't cover any duration.  Do you have to use it for each attack?  Does it last a scene?

I'm finding my personal reactions suspect, because I want to have blocks last an exchange, while armor seems like it should last a scene, but that seems a contradiction.

Comment: I'm away from my books at the moment, but the last time I answered a question like this, my understanding was each activation lasts for one exchange.  It definitely didn't cover the entire session, and a scene sounds too long too.  The question was specifically about a deprecated rule about always-on armor effects.

Comment: @Radhil Session was definitely far to long, I meant scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enchanted item is basically a stored and triggered spell effect.  The only rule about defensive enchanted items in particular is that they can be triggered on defense rather than requiring an action.  There is nothing to indicate a duration for any enchanted item.

So that means **the duration of the item's effect is the duration of the spell you store in it.**  You'd need to follow all the rules on p.252 that apply when setting up a defensive block spell, which by default without extra shifts applied to duration specifically, lasts a single exchange.  If you have 5 shifts to put into a block effect under the item rules (as in your above example of Block:5), you'd need to allocate only three shifts to power and two shifts into duration to get a Block:3 that'd last for 3 exchanges.  All the other spell block rules would apply, it could still be destroyed by a penetrating attack, etc.

So the only rules you'd still have to check in with would be the uses per session.  A crafter should keep in mind that even a used-up item can be triggered, but for the cost of one shift of mental stress.  So keep that in mind when trying to balance out the item budget.